# gcc compiler error: Invalid character conversion

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors

ALL,

I am trying to compile my application from the console in Linux with gcc-5.4.

I'm getting this error:

```
  CXX      libmysql_lib_la-database_mysql.lo
../../libmysql/database_mysql.cpp: In member function 'virtual int MySQLDatabase::GetFieldProperties(const wstring&, const wstring&, const wstring&, Field*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t> >&)':
../../libmysql/database_mysql.cpp:1594:26: error: converting to execution character set: Invalid argument
     std::wstring query = L"SELECT * FROM abcatcol WHERE abc_tnam = \'abcß\' AND abc_ownr = \'\' AND abc_cnam = \'id\';";
```

How do I fix it?

Moreover trying to compile this line from MSVC didn't produce any errors.

TIA!!

Comment: The problem is presumably the `ß` in the (wide character) string; the rest is unexceptionable.  At issue will be: what code set are you using; what code set is the compiler expecting; what code set does it think will be in use at runtime (that'll be the 'execution character set').  I'm not sure which variation on the theme of rabbit hole you're about to vanish down. Maybe you can circumvent the trouble by using placeholders instead of encoding the strings literally in the query.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I'm trying to debug why the query with the placeholders return error. And so I put in the actual data to see if it will return the same error. As for the error in question - I'm using Gentoo Linux (US version), so the only locales available are en_US and UTF-8.